# Variable in Range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to use a variable in Range?

I have some cells called `test1`, `test2`, etc

Range("test1") works like Range("A1"), but Range(variable) or Range("variable") does not work.

I want to set a variable `cellName` and when I loop through `test1`, `test2`, the cells called `test1`, and `test2`, does something.

```
Dim cellName as String
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("C5:C8")

For each cell In rng
  cellName = cell.Value
  Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("cellName").Value = "Good"
Next cell
```

Comment: How do you *loop thru test1, test2*?

Comment: Yes, and `Range("test1")` works. I just don't get the `Range(variable)` when variable is named "test1"

Comment: you need to *write* something into a variable. Like `x = "test1"`, then you can use `Range(x)`.

Comment: Are these worksheets in the workbook containing this code? What is the name of the worksheet with the range `C5:C8`? Should it actually be `C5:CLastRow`? Does it contain the names from the cells in `Sheet2`? Are you trying to loop through the range and check if the name exists and then write `Good` to the named cell? What is the scope of the named cells (worksheet or workbook)? Please add these and any other clarifications to your post. Screenshots might do wonders, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub test()
Dim cellName As String
Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In Range("C5:C8")
  cellName = rng.Value
  Worksheets("Hoja1").Range(cellName).Value = "Good"
Next rng

Set rng = Nothing


End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to modify cells in C5:C8 you just need to do :

```
Dim cellName as String
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("C5:C8")

For each cell In rng
  cell = "Good"
Next cell
```

Comment: That is now what the OP requested help with

Comment: Didn't understand your comment !!!